# Brew - undo whatever it just did for installation

Tags: macos, homebrew

Disclaimer - I am not a Mac person.

I wanted a very simple text editor that I could save a small python script with. TextEdit wouldn't let me save a .py, so I was perplexed - I'll just install `gedit` which I see on machines all the time. Must be small. So I ran :

```
brew install gedit
```

10 mins later, it was still installing, wasting tons of my precious 256GB disk space. I cancelled it, but now I have no idea how to uninstall what brew dumped into my machine. This is really bothering me.

Can anyone help me to get rid of that? `brew uninstall gedit` doesn't do anything.

Comment: When you've finally gotten the answer you need to fix this problem, look into BBEdit. BTW/ TextEdit is perfectly content to save a .py file - you just need to change the file to Plain Text in the Format menu. TextEdit defaults to Rich Text Format, which is why it wouldn't let you save the file with the .py extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Source/more info: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/uninstall-homebrew-from-mac/8696

---

For future reference, you probably would have been better off to let it finish installing and the uninstalling it. Hopefully their uninstall script is robust enough to help. If not, you might want to ask for help on the Brew forum at https://discourse.brew.sh where Brew developers help users with issues.

Comment: This looks like it'll take out my python3, Xcode, command line tools and other brew installed packages, no? and yeah you're probably right... but I panicked haha